# definition of ākāśa in Sanskrit. Does ākāśa mean śūnya?

Tags: scripture, vedas, sanskrit

I'd like to know that in Sanskrit or in Sanskrit dictionary if "ākāśa" have the meaning of "śūnya",nothing or void or zero? Some Buddhist claim that ākāśa mean śūnya. Therefore Buddha never taught voidism. But Lord Buddha taught śūnya philosophy to atheists, there is no God nor soul.  Not ākāśa which is one of 5 elements.

Comment: Whatever it means ākāśa is  likely the weird transformation thing of akāśa

Comment: Akasha is a tatva/element of Prakriti defined in Samkhya and Kashmir_Shaivism(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tattva_(Shaivism)). What Buddhists call sunya or zero, is known as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neti_neti in Vedas and a definition of Nirguna Brahman or Atman. Do you really think God or truth changes with costumes and customs of different people? The natural body costume i.e. man-woman structure is same for everyone as its maker is one, and its metaphysics contain elements like akasha, agni, vayu etc., Its because of Kaliyuga, age of ignorance, several religions and languages exist.

Comment: Buddha was asked, “What have you gained from meditation?” He replied, “Nothing!” Then he continued, “However, let me tell you what I have lost: anger, anxiety, depression, insecurity, and fear of old age and death." Buddhists are called atheists because they reject God, but have all Hindus or Abrahamics seen God to be called theist?Acceptance or rejection of any bookish belief without any proof is mere a weak superstitious belief, not actual truth or God realization, hence easy rice bag conversions that happens between modern religions which are just customs & costumes for gaining followers.

Answer (score 0):

Sanskrit is very complex language akasa means avakkasa that is niruktha pata.. means space to do things its not void thats why vinyaka is called vingna harthara meaning one who destroys obstacles.  that is why vinayaka is akasa abhimani devata, even though there are many like, 1. Lakshmi 2. shiva 3. Parvati 4. Vinaya  have given in order, There is no room for obstacle that is akasa that why vinayaka is devata for akasa

Sunya - niruktha pata sam - total bliss or ananda -ya -gnana knowledge-- sam iti ya sunya - one whose body is bliss and knowledge to the fullest. After Niruktha Pata.. Now Buddha says God is Sunya. what is the meaning you derive.. God is Bliss and knowledge.. Buddhist followers Take the literal meaning like advaita..Aham Brahmasmi Im God

Note:
Now your statement that Buddha preached lie to delude evil minded person. Now being Vaishnavite One should not see any wrong in God i.e. Buddha or vishnu or krishna. Now you see unintentionaly we are attaching wrong or dosha to God (God is one who can also preach lie to delude) Now this assumption dangerous because if According to Hindusim and your statement that Buddha preached Lie). now buddhist claim that its only hindusim which is following Lie. the concept of Krishna preaching will become lie. as buddha avatara is after krishna. Who will determine which one is lie. So its only our assumption is wrong, God or Avatara never preach lie that is understanding one should have. Then get the correct interpertation of Buddha teaching according to sashtras.. Then one being hindu can see that buddha teaching is corresponding hindu sashtras such as vedas.

Comment: Dear Prasanna R, thank you for your advice and suggestions. To make atheists to follow Dharma, Lord Buddha denid the existence of GOD, because atheists never accept the existence of GOD. Therefore they never followed any Dharma in the begging of Kali yuga. Because they were envious of GOD. That's why Lord Buddha deceived them and same time He save atheists from going to hell.“Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord will appear as Buddha, the son of Añjanā, in the province of Gayā, just for the purpose of deluding those who are envious of the faithful theist.”Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam [1.3.24]

Comment: I would say because of his statements people got deluded, but the statements have dual meaning.. Lokham shanikam and God is sunya Lokham shanikam is universe will always be changing and God is poorna gnana anand swaroopa for theist hindu. The words of God can never go wrong that is my point its capability of perceiver to preceive it wrongly.. and follow it accordingly even in purnas lot of statements are delusion if taken verbatim.. sankrit is very tricky and slippery langauage

Comment: @Radhikadasi Buddha never denied the existence of God, he just never spoke about it.

Comment: @Aupakarana Abhibhaa  Yes, Lord Buddha never told that there is no GOD, but He taught VOID. That means everything come from NOTHIG. Because of this VOIDISM, asuras think there is no GOD.

Comment: @ Aupakarana Abhibhaa Sri Vamanadeva and Mohini deceived asras to protect devotees, thiests.dyūtaṁ chalayatām asmi  "I am the gambling of cheats." BG10.36

Comment: @Radhikadasi 1. Asuras don't always think there is no God  2. Buddhism has a lot of variance in it and the voidism comes from a later sect.

Comment: @ Aupakarana Abhibhaa, Asuras think they are GOD, like Hiranyakasipu and Ravana, etc. In their minds, "there is no GOD because I am GOD". Asuras are all envious the Supreme Authority. asatyam apratiṣṭhaṁ te
jagad āhur anīśvaram : "They say that this world is unreal, with no foundation, no God in control." (BG16.8)  Voidism are there since this material world begun. Sunyavadi means voidism according to Srila Prabhupada. And not only Buddhism, other religions have many sects.

Comment: you are sterotyping King Prahlad, Bali all are great devotees of Lord vishnu. Not all asuras have hatred towards vishnu, Infact many Asuras know clearly that Supreme personality of God Head Lord Sriman Narayana clearly..

Comment: Mohaka Avatara of vishnu is mohini and buddha is what well known but infact every avatara is mohaka also, along with gnana and bala karya. why because Lord is all attractive nobody can escape his enchantment during mohini avatara Lord Shiva wants to marry Mohini came running towards Mohini avatar even in presence his consort Parvati In Rama avatara surpanka was attracted towards Rama even during very old age..

Comment: @ Aupakarana Abhibhaa,Yes, They don't care GOD and Dharma, because they think they are God and they are rule, in other words selfish, they think they are the center of the world. "O son of Pṛthā, in this world there are two kinds of created beings. One is called divine and the other demoniac." BG16.6 "They say that this world is unreal, with no foundation, no God in control." BG16.8 Sunnya voidism is original teaching of Lord Buddha,but the followers of Buddha later changed the concept sunnya to ākāśa because voidism can't explain the cause of creation of this material world.

Comment: @ Prasanna R  I'm sorry I don't understand what you wrote above. But Prahladha Maharaja is the pure devotee of Krsna since from his birth even though he took his birth among demons family. Bali Maharaj became a pure devotee after he gave up everything and completely surrender to Sri Vamanadeva.

Comment: With due respect Radhikadasi what i meant akasa doesnt mean void as stated in sanskrit dictionary and also Asura just means they are not devatha  one who are turned towards material world or hankering the sense instead of God, But they know God is there. but there are good asura also like vibheesna.. after Ravanas death many asuras are turned towards vishnu by vibhisana.. similarly by prahlad.. all his parivara Asura are infact bhaktha of Narasimha..

Comment: Dear Prasanna R, Your mention about "akasa",that is what I really want to know.Thank you so much.  "It should be understood that all species of life, O son of Kuntī, are made possible by birth in this material nature, and that I am the seed-giving father."BG14.4  All living entities, suras and asuras, are His children. If asuras surrender to the Absolute Truth Sri Krsna,then asuras will turn to suras,devotees of the Lord. If the soul's conscious become completely pure,then he can go back to Vaikunta, spiritual world, which is our destination, our eternal Home, no repeating birth and death.